Can't remove Nodejs symlink in Windows
The reason I'm trying to remove the nodejs symlink is to try and do a clean reinstall of nodejs. There was a bug that I've encountered previously in trying to switch versions by using the command nvm use <package version>, where the version just would not switch. I'm pretty sure this problem is the reason behind it.
Trying to remove the symlink file throws an error:
Require permission from Administrators to make changes to this folder
I've already tried other methods such as using takeown in cmd to take ownership over the file, which actually returns a sucessful output:
SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "C:\Program Files\nodejs" now owned by the administrators group. but even so, when trying to delete the file it still would throw the same error shown previously.
I've tried manually setting permissions from the file's Properties -> Security, added the Administrator account, and tried setting Full Control permission for Administrator(me), but that couldn't go through. A different error shows up trying to do that
I've already tried using a tool from Window's named File Locksmith which is supposed to unlock the File but it doesn't work too.
Now I'm all out of ideas trying to remove this file/symlink.
EDIT:
I've also tried changing the User Account Control Settings from Default to Never Notify, but that does not work too

Inspecting the nodejs symlink file's permissions, SYSTEM and BUILTIN group both has full permissions over the Symlink file but Administrator(myself) does not, therefore I've used a Powershell tool called Invoke-CommandAs to run the rm -Force C:\Program Files\nodejs command as SYSTEM; to be specific, the full command is:
Invoke-CommandAs -ScriptBlock { rm -Force "C:\Program Files\nodejs" } -AsSystem

Not sure if anyone is going to encounter the same problem as I do but this worked.
